# Use variables in MariaDB/MySQL script

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm writing a script I'd like to be able to run as I please. Unfortunately, the SQL is very long and I'd like to be able to change a couple things. However, I'm unable to access a variable in the script.

Here's an example:

```
SET @MaxResults = 3;
SELECT a, b, c FROM ...<lots of content>... LIMIT @MaxResults;
```

For some reason this is a syntax error and I can't understand why. What's the best way to define a variable in MariaDB?

Comment: with the select to take that variable and save it?

Answer (score 1):

## User-defined variables in MySQL

MySQL recognizes different types of variables. The first type is user-defined variables, identified by an @ symbol used as a prefix. In MySQL, user-defined variables can be accessed without first declaring or initializing them. If you do so, a NULL value is assigned to the variable when it is initialized.

## Declaring local variables in MySQL

Local variables do not need the @ prefix in their names, but they must be declared before they can be used. To declare a local variable, you can use the DECLARE statement or use it as a parameter within a STORED PROCEDURE statement.

When declaring a local variable, you can optionally assign a default value to it. If you assign no default value, the variable is initialized with a NULL value.

Each variable lives within a scope, delimited by the BEGIN ... END block containing its declaration.

**For Example declare :**

```
DECLARE variable TYPE [DEFAULF VALUE]

DECLARE a INT; 
DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE a VARCHAR(12);
DECLARE a VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT '';

DECLARE a CHAR;
DECLARE a CHAR DEFAULT '';

DECLARE a FLOAT;
DECLARE a FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0;

DECLARE a BOOLEAN;
DECLARE a BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;
```

**Other Example :**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetUpdatedPrices(itemcount INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE factor DECIMAL(5, 2);
    SET factor:=3.45;
    SELECT PartNo, Description, itemcount * factor * ListPrice FROM Catalogue;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You must define the type and optionally the value it contains, for example if it is a counter it is logical that the value of the default variable is 0.

And the rest as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use user-defined variables as the argument for `LIMIT`.

The documentation for [LIMIT in the MariaDB knowledgebase](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/limit/) does not make this totally clear.

In the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), it is more clear:

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Because user-defined variables (the kind with the `@` sigil) are not typed, they are effectively strings. Strings are not allowed as arguments to `LIMIT`.

The same restrictions apply to MariaDB. MySQL and MariaDB are not always compatible, but in this case their behavior is the same.